# Azure CosmosDB why isn't the 'id' field automatically added when inserting into Azure CosmosDB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have recently started getting this error when I debug my python function app: `(BadRequest) Message: {"Errors":["One of the specified inputs is invalid"]}`

The function app works perfectly well for my coworkers and they are not getting this error.
The error occurs whenever I attempt to access the azure cosmos db.

Sample

```
item = { "firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe"}
container.upsert_item(item)
```

The issue seems to be that insert into the database is missing the "id" field. If I add this field to the item before calling upsert_item(item) it works correctly.

Why did I not originally need to do this (coworkers don't need to) and what setting did I change to stop it from auto adding the id field?

I am using visual studio code, coding in python, installed the azure tools extension. I have tried  deleting the code from disk and re-cloning it, removing all the extensions and reinstalling them, and I even completely uninstalled visual studio code. Whatever setting changed is still there.

**EDIT**

Added the container properties

```
Container properties {'id': 'person', 'indexingPolicy': {'indexingMode': 'consistent', 'automatic': True, 'includedPaths': [{'path': '/*'}], 'excludedPaths': [{'path': '/"_etag"/?'}]}, 'partitionKey': {'paths': ['/lastname'], 'kind': 'Hash'}, 'uniqueKeyPolicy': {'uniqueKeys': []}, 'conflictResolutionPolicy': {'mode': 'LastWriterWins', 'conflictResolutionPath': '/_ts', 'conflictResolutionProcedure': ''}, 'geospatialConfig': {'type': 'Geography'}, 'analyticalStorageTtl': -1, '_rid': 'O-pDAPQSY5Y=', '_ts': 1654191756, '_self': 'dbs/O-pDAA==/colls/O-pDAPQSY5Y=/', '_etag': '"00003b31-0000-0100-0000-6298f68c0000"', '_docs': 'docs/', '_sprocs': 'sprocs/', '_triggers': 'triggers/', '_udfs': 'udfs/', '_conflicts': 'conflicts/'}
```

Comment: Remember that an upsert is going to check against existing documents, for matching `id` (to decide whether to insert or update), making `id` required (vs a call to `create_item()` which would generate a default `id` if you didn't provide it).

Comment: @DavidMakogon - I changed the code to use create_item(item) and I instead get `(BadRequest) Message: {"Errors":["The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing. Learn more: https:\/\/aka.ms\/CosmosDB\/sql\/errors\/missing-id"]}`
So some setting changed somewhere that now requires me to input an `id` when I didn't originally have to

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have CosmosDB choose the ID of the inserted item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287103/have-cosmosdb-choose-the-id-of-the-inserted-item)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to my issue.
I had updated azure cosmos db to the latest version (4.3.0) globaly (which is why it only affected me, should have put it in the requirements.txt instead) which does not allow for the automatic creation of `id`s.

There is a single line change (from 4.2.0 to 4.3.0) in the `upsert_item(...)` function that is difficult to spot (worded very similarly) when you are looking at a wall of code.

[Azure-Cosmos-4.3.0 github link to the line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/0af8deab3958acfae24cae2e24060b576c71b076/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/azure/cosmos/container.py#L500)

Annoyingly this line is hard coded. Why they decided to prevent the user from auto generating `id`s is beyond me.

Comment: You can easily generate the id on the client side if you need to by using the UUID generators. Having said that, when you generate random IDs, it would be hard for you to track them and then it will be difficult to perform point reads where you would need Partition Key and Item ID.

Answer (score -1):

If people are still looking for this:
You can now add the `enable_automatic_id_generation` flag to the `create_item` method.

Example:

```py
result = container.create_item(
    {
        "data": "hello world",
    },
    enable_automatic_id_generation=True,
)
```